# How to wake STM32F103 by RTC using HAL libraries / Registers?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, rtc, sleep, hal-library

I've started digging into STM32F103 using HAL Libraries and raw registers. It's the first time to program at such low level.

Anyway following a video I've successfully implemented "Standby" mode.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O82rj9qxkgs

I need an RTC to wake it up instead of a button. So I read the reference manual without really knowing how to start and finish it up.

[image: RTC Simplified Block Diagram]

Searching the internet, I found 2 main categories of sources: sources using Standard Peripheral Library (SPL), which is not my case. And sources using registers.

Anyway couldn't successfully implement the "RTC Wake Up" method.

I'm using this [resource](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000A1jnny/stm32f103-wont-wakeup-from-standby-mode-using-rtc-alarm) as my code starter.

Anyway, because I don't need RTC Calendar, I've removed any setting/reading date/time as I don't need them.

And I put a LED toggle to:

```
void HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc) {
   HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GPIO_Port,LED_Pin);
}
```

What I observe now: the MCU toggles the LED At the start of sleeping (couldn't measure time), then continues sleeping without running `main()` again.

- The MCU wakes up successfully using WAKEUP positive edge via a button.

Comment: Could you tell us what you want to do more precisely ? Periodically wake up/standby ? One shot wake up after a certain amount of time ? How much time ? You seem to have already implemented a call to an Alarm so what do you want then ? I already did it on a F072 so I think I can help you.

Comment: Ofcourse @MathieuG. I want to want to wake up the MCU periodically with changeable time in seconds and minutes. ("every 15 seconds", "every 60 seconds"..). doing some stuff (read sensor and send data) then go Standby mode.... In my code I've set the Alarm at 5 seconds, but it does respond immediately after sleep. Ask for the code if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used an Alarm to generate a 1 hour sleep in STOP mode before automatically wake up to do some stuffs and then shut off. I configured 3 wake up conditions :

- 2 external interrupts
- The 59min timeout.

Here is the source for a STM32F072. The source must be really close for your STM32F103:

```
RTC_AlarmTypeDef sAlarm;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

/* Enable 2 external interruptions and configure EXTI lines in interruption mode */
NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_15_IRQn);
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_15_IRQn, 0, 0);
NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI2_3_IRQn);
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI2_3_IRQn, 0, 0);
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Alertb_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
HAL_GPIO_Init(Alertb_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = BPb_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
HAL_GPIO_Init(BPb_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* Enable the Alarm A : mask only the minute and program a time in 59 minutes */
HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes = (sTime.Minutes + 59)%60;
sAlarm.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
sAlarm.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY | RTC_ALARMMASK_HOURS | RTC_ALARMMASK_SECONDS;
sAlarm.AlarmTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
sAlarm.AlarmTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
sAlarm.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_ALL;
sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_DATE;
sAlarm.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
if (HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &sAlarm, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
{
    Error_Handler();
}

/* Go into stop mode + internal voltage regulator in low power mode :
 * System is awaken by :
 * - The 2 previous EXT interrupt
 * - The programmed ALARM */
HAL_SuspendTick();
__HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFE); // Here the uc is stuck during 59 min or until an EXTI event occurred
HAL_ResumeTick();

/* Re-init system clock configuration after STOP mode exit */
SystemClock_Config();
```

Here is how ST does the Alarm config in their demonstration projects :

```
/**
  * @brief  Configure the current time and date.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void RTC_AlarmConfig(void)
{
  RTC_DateTypeDef  sdatestructure;
  RTC_TimeTypeDef  stimestructure;
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef salarmstructure;

  /*##-1- Configure the Date #################################################*/
  /* Set Date: Tuesday February 18th 2014 */
  sdatestructure.Year = 0x14;
  sdatestructure.Month = RTC_MONTH_FEBRUARY;
  sdatestructure.Date = 0x18;
  sdatestructure.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_TUESDAY;

  if(HAL_RTC_SetDate(&RtcHandle,&sdatestructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler(); 
  } 

  /*##-2- Configure the Time #################################################*/
  /* Set Time: 02:20:00 */
  stimestructure.Hours = 0x02;
  stimestructure.Minutes = 0x20;
  stimestructure.Seconds = 0x00;

  if(HAL_RTC_SetTime(&RtcHandle,&stimestructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler(); 
  }  

  /*##-3- Configure the RTC Alarm peripheral #################################*/
  /* Set Alarm to 02:20:30 
     RTC Alarm Generation: Alarm on Hours, Minutes and Seconds */
  salarmstructure.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
 salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x20;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x30;

  if(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&RtcHandle,&salarmstructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler(); 
  }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My situation is a bit different. As I want to wake from Standby Mode... By reading the Reference manual I came across this sentence : "To wakeup from Stop mode with an RTC alarm event, it is necessary to:
• Configure the EXTI Line 17 to be sensitive to rising edge
• Configure the RTC to generate the RTC alarm
To wakeup from Standby mode, there is no need to configure the EXTI Line 17."

So I think your answer is more than enough. Just needs some modifications.. Can you share your RTC Init function So I keep up in the same page.

Comment: I connect Vbat to 3.3V, Was this the case in your schematic ?

Comment: I'm trying to merge your code to mine (F103), Came across several issues : 
-Should I read BKUP using `HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR1)` ? And sAlarm has no members/fields than Alarm and AlarmTime. AlarmTime doesn't have more than `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds`. So from `TimeFormat` to `AlarmDateWeekDaySel` fields are not present in F103 HAL. Are they mandatory ?

Comment: Yes connect 3v3 to Vbat to allow RTC clock to run. Indeed ST has modified its driver source a bit. It seems easier to use Alarm now. You can directly set the Alarm hours, min and seconds to what you want. I will edit my answer with a ST example I found.

Comment: Unfortunately the bat is connected to 3v3 but It doesn't wake up from RTC.Can you share all your RTC initialization codes ?

Comment: First debug your app to see if you can make your rtc run and give you date and time. This is mandatory. Do you use a 32kHz Cristal to make the RTC run ?

Comment: Yes I use the on board 32kHz oscillator (BluePill)

Comment: Hi, I've switched my code with this one provided [here](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkfYv/stm32f103-rtc-issues) Which everything after is ran : go to standby mode , wake up. however switched my code back and commented this, It set the time and date perfectly, but not after a power down cycle. I'll investigate what this code brings to me.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir waking up from standby mode trigger a reset, it's almost equivalent than  reset manually the chip and start program at reset handler (then go to main()). Every register contains is lost, except these from RTC so you have to check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can active it by alarm, but you can active **WakeUp** in CubeMX:

(**NOTE**: The option is not available for **STM32F1xx**. The picture is for **STM32F4xx**)

[image]

Don't forget to also enable the interrupt.

OK, now copy and comment these lines in `MX_RTC_Init(void)`:

```
  /** Enable the WakeUp
  */
  if (HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&hrtc, 0, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

Now, change the main function as this:

```
/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    printf("Starting\n");
    printf("Before Delay\n");
    HAL_Delay(5000);
    printf("After Delay\n");
    HAL_Delay(3000);

    //Check if woken up from standby mode:
    if (__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB) != RESET)
    {
        __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB);  // clear the flag

        printf("Waking up from the standby mode\n");

        HAL_PWR_DisableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1);
        
        HAL_RTCEx_DeactivateWakeUpTimer(&hrtc);
    }
    
    //Clear the WU flag
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);
    __HAL_RTC_WAKEUPTIMER_CLEAR_FLAG(&hrtc, RTC_FLAG_WUTF);
    
    HAL_PWR_EnableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1);

     /*## Configure the Wake up timer ###########################################*/
  /*  RTC Wake-up Interrupt Generation:
      Wake-up Time Base = (RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV /(LSI))
      ==> WakeUpCounter = Wake-up Time / Wake-up Time Base

      To configure the wake up timer to 10s the WakeUpCounter is set to 0x1770:
        RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV = RTCCLK_Div16 = 16
        Wake-up Time Base = 16 /(32KHz) = 0.0005 seconds
        ==> WakeUpCounter = ~10s/0.0005s = 20000 = 0x1770 */

    if (HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&hrtc, 20000, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV16) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    
    printf("Going to standby mode\n");
    
    HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode();
    
    printf("After Standby Mode\n"); //This line is never printed.
    
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Call init function for freertos objects (in freertos.c) */
  MX_FREERTOS_Init();
  /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();

  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```